# python delete multiple items from list by index, including negative index

Tags: python, list

I know that deleting multiple non-adjacent elements from a list by index has already been covered, but what if the indexes are negative? For example both list[len(list) - 1] and list[-1] both refer to the same element, but they are different numbers when stored, and get sorted differently if we try the “delete the larger indexes first” strategy.

Comment: Could you please add some code to explain what you mean? How could list elements could have negative indices? The first element is indexed by `[0]` and the last element is indexed by `[-1]` which is equal to `[len(l)-1]`.

Comment: @albert There is no `-1` index in Python lists, that's all the logic it applies to while getting the value, check my answer below.

Comment: If all the indices are negative the strategy is the same, you just invert the logic. If you have mixed positive and negative, you need to normalize them first.

Comment: the reason I’m asking is because I’m trying to avoid dealing with len(list) because I’m really only working with the beginning and end parts of the list i.e. i = 1, 2, 3, -2, -1. These values are stored as 'keys' to remember where the elements are if I want to delete them later

Comment: If you are sure there will be no ambiguity, you can use positives and negatives in your logic. Treat negative values as greater than positive values.

Answer (score 0):

There are no negative indices in `Python Lists`, when you try with negative index this what happens in Python...

```
if (index < 0) {
    index  = index + len(list) # this is just a pseudo code
}
```

Python applies logic to get the values by using `index`.

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l[-1]
4
>>> l[-2]
3
```

Here it applied well because we just tried `-1 and -2`, if you go beyond `len` of list in negatives like, above list length is `5`, suppose if you try for `l[-6]` it tries to apply the above logic and checks this `5 + (-6) ==> -1`, still the value is in negatives and there is no index with `-1` in the list, this throws an `IndexError` exception like below.

```
>>> l[-6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

**BTW** this is the logic Python applies for `list insert`..

```
if (where < 0) {
    where += n;
    if (where < 0) # here "where" is index that we trying to insert
        where = 0; # "n" is length of the list
}
if (where > n)
    where = n;
```

Here `where` is the `index` value the one try to `insert into list`. and `n` is length of the list.

You can go through below link for more info about lists ..

http://gsb-eng.com/pythonlistinternals/